# How to modify datatype in function calling?

Tags: c++, arguments, overlap

I have the following class

```
  template<class TDataType> 
  void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId, 
                     const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
                     const TDataType& Value)
  {
      mpModeler->SetProperties(PropertiesId, rVariable, Value);
  }

template<typename TDataType, std::size_t N>
void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId,
    const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable,
    const TDataType(&Value)[N])
{
    mpModeler->SetProperties(PropertiesId, rVariable, Value);
}
```

The function `mpModeler::SetProperties` is defined as follows

```
  template<class TDataType> 
  void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId, 
                     const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
                     const TDataType& Value)
  {
      if (mpModel->GetProperties(PropertiesId).get() == 0)
      {
          mpModel->AddProperties(PropertiesId, Properties::Pointer(new Properties(*mpModel)));
      }

      PropertyFunction<TDataType>::Pointer constant_property(new ConstantProperty<TDataType>(Value));

      mpModel->GetProperties(PropertiesId)->SetProperty(rVariable, constant_property);
  }
```

and it can be called like this:

```
pKernel->SetProperties(i, *double_variable, regionmapi[0]);
```

where regionmapi is defined as

```
double *regionmapi;
```

or like this:

```
pKernel->SetProperties(i, *double_variable, tmp3);
```

where tmp3 is defined as

```
double tmp3[3];
```

but now the following error displayed:

```
Error   7   error C2782: 'void Kratos::Modeler::SetProperties(Kratos::Modeler::IndexType,const Kratos::Variable<TDataType> &,const TDataType &)' : template parameter 'TDataType' is ambiguous
```

could anyone help me to take a look at it?

Thanks,

Tang Laoya

Comment: First of all, why not make `regionmapi` a `std::vector` to begin with? Secondly, are you sure you want to force the type of `value` to `double*` instead of `TDataType`?

Comment: As for your problem, do you want to call the original `SetProperties` for all elements in the `value` array?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, but I don't know how to pass the value array to TDataType Value, can you give me some hints?

Comment: The input data is 'double *value', but I don't know how to convert it to TDataType Value, thanks

Comment: What *is* `TDataType`? Will it always be the same? Will it be the same type as the base type of the `values` array (i.e. `double` in your example)? Will it be compatible with `double`? Have you tried using it without any "converting"? How about a simple `static_cast`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first example just works, but only a scalar double value is passed, I need to pass an array with length size. The TDataType is just  defined as template<class TDataType>

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow you yet, but you want to pass the *array* (or vector) as argument to the original `SetProperties` function? Without modifying the original `SetProperties` function? Then let me ask you this: Do you *have* to pass the array or vector? Can't you just loop over the array and call the original `SetProperties` function for every value in the array?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have to pass multiple values to TDataType, the mpModeler::SetProperties  is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the array by const reference, via a template, and its size will be automatically deduced:

```
template<class TDataType, std::size_t N> 
void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId, 
               const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
               const TDataType(&Value)[N])
```

but you need an additional template non-type parameter `size_t N`. Simple example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TDataType, size_t N>
void f(const TDataType(&Value)[N])
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << N;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    f(arr); // displays 5
}
```

The downside is that it won't work with pointers.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't know how to do, could you please give me more details? Thanks

Comment: @TangLaoya see the updated edit for how the declaration of your function may look like.

Comment: Thank you very much. I modified as you suggested, but now the error is: Error 7 error C2782: 'void Kratos::Modeler::SetProperties(Kratos::Modeler::IndexType,const Kratos::Variable<TDataType> &,const TDataType &)' : template parameter 'TDataType' is ambiguous

Comment: From looking at the error you posted, it seems that `Kratos::Modeler::SetProperties` doesn't take the array by reference (last parameter is `const TDataType&`, but it should be `const TDataType(&)[N]`). You'd need to modify your `Kratos::Modeler::SetProperty` also.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited the question and added the real instance of 'Setproperties', could you please help me to take a look at it?

Comment: @TangLaoya if you invoke `SetProperty` from another class inside your function, then the latter has to take the array by reference also. As you see, it's a bit tedious, and you should really be using a `std::vector` here, which can be passed via your original template.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I updated the question, could you please help me to take a look at it?

Comment: @TangLaoya you have to match the parameters. You need to pass an array to your function, but it looks like you pass `regionmapi[0]`. You have to pass an array, so pass `regionmapi`. But, as I said, it won't work for pointers (`regionmapi` is a pointer). If you need to use pointers, then you should go back to your original design. I cannot help you more, as the code looks quite involved and you don't have a minimal verifiable and compilable example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply. I have updated the question. When passing array, I used `double tmp3[3];` instead of  `double *regionmapi;`. Thanks.